# How to populate time dropdown in 15 min intervals 8 hours from current time

Tags: php, time

I have successfully populated a drop down to display time in 15 min. intervals  and default to the nearest time but I need to limit it to 8 hours ahead of the current time and have an option of "ASAP" in place of the closest current time.

For example it is now 3:30 PM

So the html should look like this...

```
<option selected="selected">ASAP</option> Time = 3:30 pm
<option>3:45 pm</option>
<option>4:00 pm</option>
<option>4:15 pm</option>
<option>4:30 pm</option>
<option>4:45 pm</option>
```

etc...

Here is my current code...

```
<?
$time = time();
$rounded_time = $time % 900 > 450 ? $time += (900 - $time % 900):  $time -= $time % 900;

$start = strtotime('12:00am');
$end = strtotime('11:59pm');

for( $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 900) 
{
    $selected = ( ($rounded_time - $i) % (86400) == 0) ? ' selected=""' : '';
    echo '<option' . $selected . '>' . date('g:i a', $i) . '</option>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Well at least we know you didn't cut & paste this code from some other site.

Comment: Including your code isn't enough, what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: "but I need to limit it to 8 hours ahead of the current time" That sounds like 8 hours before the current time, and your example shows starting at the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime`:

```php
$start = new DateTime;
$start->setTime($start->format('G'), ceil($start->format('i') / 15) * 15);

$end = clone $start;
$end->modify('+8 hour');

while ($start <= $end) {
    echo '<option>' . $start->format('g:i a') . '</option>';
    $start->modify('+15 minute');
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/85092)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the for loop by changing `$start` to your current time (which in your example is `$rounded_time`), and `$end` to the time plus 8 hours. You'd manually add the ASAP option before the loop.